# Problem using expectation and variance formulas

Tags: probability

Let the number of cars sold per month have the following distribution
\begin{array}{r|ccccc}
x&  2&  3&  4&  5&  7\\\hline
p(x)& 0.1 & 0.3 & 0.3 & 0.2 &0.1
\end{array}

There are also the formulas

1. $\mu = E(X)=\sum xP(x)$
2. $\sigma^2=\sum [(x-E(X))^2P(X)]$

I'm not sure if I'm following the above formulas when I am doing my calculations below?

$\text{mean} = (2)(0.1)+(3)(0.3)+(4)(0.3)+(5)(0.2)+(7)(0.1) = 4$
$\text{variance} = (2-4)^2(0.1)+(3-4)^2(0.3)+(4-4)^2(0.3)+(5-4)^2(0.2)+(7-4)^2(0.1)= 1.8$
$\text{standard deviation} = 1.34164$

Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: Apart from sloppy notation, problem presentation, grammar, and minor typos, you have the right idea.  Remember to look at how your post is going to be *displayed* by looking at the preview window, not at the window in which you are typing.  A new line is not started after a single enter-key, but instead after *two* enter keys here, so parts of your post become hard to read.  E.g. `...(7)(0.1) = 4 variance = (2-4)^2(0.1)...` should have apparently had a new line inbetween the "4" and the "variance."

Comment: Please learn to type up your posts properly and follow the textbook's notation closely. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: A few things to note: $\sqrt{1.8}$ is *not* **equal** to $1.34164$, it is *approximately equal to*.  As such, you should use $\approx$ (`\approx`) or $\approxeq$ (`\approxeq`) if you choose to write the *inexact* value of $1.34164$ instead of the *exact* value of $\sqrt{1.8}$.  Further, since the values were nice this time, it worked out nicely to use the form above.  One can prove that $Var(X)$ is also equal via algebraic manipulation to $Var(X)=E[X^2]-(E[X])^2$.  This alternate form may prove to be more useful in the case that the mean is not a nice number.

Comment: JMoravitz. Thanks  for your advice. My apologies for being sloppy.

Comment: "Problem using expectation and variance formulas" Sorry but *which* problem?